# System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled

Tags: c#, file, access-denied, unhandled-exception, file-access

I am getting a access denied exception. How can I fix this?

Here is the exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled   HResult=-2147024891
>   Message=Access to the path 'c:\message.txt' is denied.
>   Source=mscorlib

Here is the code:

```
    public static void WriteToFile(string s)
    {
        fs = new FileStream("c:\\message.txt",
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(s);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

EDIT: It works if I run vs2012 as administrator, but is there a way or a reason to do it as normal user?

And this works:

```
    public static void WriteToFile(string s)
    {
        fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\KristjanBEstur\Documents\message.txt",
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(s);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
        File.Delete(@"C:\Users\KristjanBEstur\Documents\message.txt");
    }
```

Comment: The file could be read-only, or you do not have permissions to write to the file.

Comment: @driis The file doesn't exist.

Comment: In that case you probably don't have write access to the directory.

Comment: @somethingsomething You should check if a file exists or not before opening it by using File.Exists(path) and then verifying file permissions by FileInfo class to make sure the file is not set to read only if it exists.

Comment: If you have UAC enabled and you are not running your application as an "Administrator" you usually don't have access to right directly to the root of the system drive.

Comment: @GrantWinney I agree,but what if the file already exists and is set to read only ? Will it not be a worth to check file permissions before doing anything on the file ?

Comment: @somethingSomething: you need to set the `FileAtrributes` property to `Normal` please check my anwer if it helps you.

Comment: Writing to root c:\ requires administrator permissions. Create other folder and write file there. for example c:\temp\message.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to run your project in administrator mode if you want access to the root directory

You can do this by adding this to the app manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Double click on `app.manifest` file and if `app.manifest` not present Right click on your project, add -> New Item -> Application Manifest File then replace this line

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with this

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
```

It will run your application with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what all might throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

One idea though... you're trying to create a file directly in the `c:` drive, which is sometimes disallowed by system policy. For the sake of troubleshooting, try creating the file somewhere else that you'd have access to, like `My Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `FileAtrributes` property of the `File` to `Normal` before accessing the file.

Try This:

```
public static void WriteToFile(string s)
    {
        String path=@"c:\message.txt";
        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
        File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Normal);
        fs = new FileStream(path,
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(s);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("File not Found!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There was a new exception when I used your code:System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Could not find file 'c:\message.txt'.
  Source=mscorlib
  FileName=c:\message.txt

Comment: @somethingSomething: now it is sure that there is no file message.txt in c: drive , did you check it?

Comment: @somethingSomething: i have edited my answer for checking file exists or not, try it and please let me know the result.

Comment: I want the file to be created if it doesn't exist. How would you do that?

Comment: The code I have works if I run vs2012 as administrator. This is the problem.

Comment: so it is clear that the file needs admin previliges to open the file, you can goto file properties,select security, from there hange the file permission for other users to open.access the file

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Mujahed's answer (I can't comment yet), you don't need `uiAccess="true"` if you just wanted to run with administrator privileges. Setting this option to true could cause you some headache (e.g. you might not be able to run your project in debug mode.)

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```