# Opening File in C# Access Denied

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I am trying to read the content of a text file but I get the 'Access to the path is denied' exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'. I've tried the following:

- Ran Vs in Administrator mode
- Checked if the file is read only
- Checked if the file is hidden
- Checked if the file has full control on all users

My code:

```
 private async void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"fullpath\TextFile.txt";
        await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
       });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting requestedExecutionLevel in your config, taken from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443808/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-was-unhandled

Comment: Just tried it out. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access all your files just like that in Windows Store apps. Please take a look at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx) for list of locations, which your app is permited to use. Also to use most of them you will have to declare suitable *Capabilities*. If your file is outside this list and/or you haven't declared capabilities, you will get *UnauthorizedException*.

Generaly store apps shouldn't access files without user knowing about it - this is by design. If you want to access file in future, you can for example pick a file with [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186456.aspx) and then access it by [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186452.aspx) or *MostRecentlyUsed*.

Comment: This line resolved my issue: StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///file.txt");. Thank you it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MarkUivari Remember that file obtained from *InstalledLocation* is *read-only*.