# Hangfire is not working in real server

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I have to schedule two task every 5 minutes in my ASP.NET C# project, create a zip file and add a log. I used hangfire to schedule my tasks, and it's working fine in local server. When I deploy it, none of them are working (zip or log is not created). When I looked into the hangfire dashboard, I saw the create zip is under `Scheduled`, create log is under `Failed` and the error message is `System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path is denied.` I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443808/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-was-unhandled) question and created a `app.manifest` and added `level="requireAdministrator"`. But this did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, first write all the methods you need to run in a new aspx page and run that page, in your case write the log function in a page and run the page you created (say `writelog.aspx`). If this prints the log, then you can try this.

Inside your schedule call function, call the page you created

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadData("yourhostaddress/writelog.aspx");
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `AppPool` that your `HangFire` instance is running. Make sure the `AppPool` identity has the permission to access the resource.

Comment: can you explain a little more, in the real server I have access only to db and ftp