# How to remove a font from Windows in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, fonts

I'm on the way to getting this method to work.

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class FontManager
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RemoveFontResourceW", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int RemoveFontResource([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpFileName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Uninstall a font from the system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fontFile">The absolute path of the font.</param>
    public static void Uninstall(string fontFile)
    {
        var targetFontFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), Path.GetFileName(fontFile));

        if (File.Exists(targetFontFile))
        {
            // Get the font name.
            PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
            fontCollection.AddFontFile(targetFontFile);
            var actualFontName = fontCollection.Families[0].Name;

            // Remove the font from the registry.
            var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts", writable: true);

            if (key.GetValueNames().Contains(actualFontName))
            {
                key.DeleteValue(actualFontName);
            }

            key.Close();

            // Remove the font from the system.
            RemoveFontResource(targetFontFile);

            // Remove the font file from the fonts directory.
            File.SetAttributes(targetFontFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(targetFontFile);

            // Broadcast a message that the fonts has changed.
            const int WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x001D;
            const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

However I can't delete the font from the Fonts directory.

```cs
// Remove the font file from the fonts directory.
File.SetAttributes(targetFontFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(targetFontFile);
```

I get this exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Fonts\JetBrainsMono-Bold.ttf' is denied.'
```

The font is properly uninstalled/unregistered from the Registry.

Is there maybe a workaround to remove/clear the uninstalled/unregistered fonts from this directory?

Comment: did you try running your programm as admin?

Comment: Yes, however it seems having the admin rights is not enough to remove something from the Fonts directory on Windows 10.

Comment: It seems it is a top-level protection from Windows, I tried if I could overwrite a font and it works. Does anyone know more about this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows moves fonts it can't physically remove into a `Deleted` hidden directory.

Here's the code to do the same with C#.

```cs
// Try to delete the font file physically.
try
{
    File.Delete(targetFontFile);
}
// Sometimes it's impossible to delete the font because it's in use by another process.
catch (Exception)
{
    // Create the hidden Deleted directory if it doesn't exist.
    var deletedDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(targetFontFile), "Deleted");
    if (!Directory.Exists(deletedDirectory))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(deletedDirectory);
        di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden;
    }

    // Move the font file into the Deleted directory.
    File.Move(targetFontFile, Path.Combine(deletedDirectory, Path.GetFileName(targetFontFile).ToUpper()));
}
```

Windows 10 renames the font file to upper case, so my code does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing font file path to user directory and also try to set the path variable for font.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand. Is there a predefined directory for the user's fonts? Or do you mean I should create a Fonts directory somewhere accessible for the user and add the absolute path of the font to install into the Registry?

Comment: There is a directory for user's fonts here: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`.

Comment: However this directory has the same problem, we can't remove anything from it with `File.Delete` (even as admin).

Comment: I meant you should create Font Directory in C:\ Fonts and try to access it.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443808/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-was-unhandled) have you checked this link??

Comment: It is only possible to delete font files after they are unregistered from the Registry and after restarting Windows.

Comment: Removing an user's font after unregistering it from Registry works without restart. Should I maybe avoid touching Windows fonts? What do you think?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid windows font because it will affect your whole system